# KVM Image file portability

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have created some KVM Virtual Machines, each running Ubuntu 11.10 and using 1 CPU and 1024MB of RAM. I wonder how portables are those images. I mean if I copy the Image files to another computer (with different hardware than the Original Host) will they work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will work.
The alternative way (If using Ubuntu) is the easiest way to do the same.

You can convert the `.img image` (row) to `.qcow2 format`.

For converting `.img` to `.qcow2` need to use command `qemu-convert`

*Please read the man page of `qemu` command for more details.*

The `.img` images are row format so it is taking much more space then `.qcow2`.